# trying to append bandname to mp3 upload using $_SESSION['bandname'];

Tags: php, html, session

Trying to append $_SESSION['bandname']; to an mp3 file upload, The concept
is when someone uploads a song it append the band name to mp3 bandname_songname.mp3 if that makes sense. here is my code so far.
the problem is with this line i think $aditionalnewFileName = $bandname.="_".$aditionofileName; this strange part is when I use the var_dump($bandname); well instead of the band name its the song I'm testing with string(88) "_police.ogg_police.ogg_police.ogg_police.ogg_police.mp3_police.mp3_police.mp3_police.wav". maybe mysqli would be more simple?

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset      ($_SESSION ['band_id'  ]))
{
$band_id  = $_SESSION ['band_id'  ];
$bandname = $_SESSION ['bandname' ];
$username = $_SESSION ['username' ];
}
var_dump($_SESSION['bandname']);

ini_set( "max_execution_time", "3600" ); // sets the maximum execution 
time of this script to 1 hour.

$uploads_dir     = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mp3';

$aditiontmp_name = $_FILES['song_name']['tmp_name']; // get client 
//side file tmp_name 
// '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_\'.]/', ''   //$_FILES['song_name']['name']);
$aditionofileName  = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_\'.]/', 
'',$_FILES['song_name']['name']); // get client side file name remove 
the special character with preg_replace function.

// remove time() to edit name of mp3
$aditionalnewFileName = $bandname.="_".$aditionofileName; //filename 
changed with current time

if ( move_uploaded_file($aditiontmp_name, 
"$uploads_dir/$aditionalnewFileName")) //Move uploadedfile
{

$uploadFile = $uploads_dir."/".$aditionalnewFileName; //Uploaded file 
path

 $ext = pathinfo($uploads_dir."/".$aditionalnewFileName, 
 PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Get the file extesion.

$uploadFilebasename = basename($uploads_dir."/".$aditionalnewFileName, 
".".$ext); //Get the basename of the file without extesion.

$exName = ".mp3";

$finalFile = $uploads_dir."/".$uploadFilebasename.$exName; //Uploaded 
file name changed with extesion .mp3

$encode_cmd = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $uploadFile -b:a 256000 $finalFile 
2>&1"; // -i means input file -b:a means bitrate 2>&1 is use for debug 
command.

exec($encode_cmd,$output); //Execute an external program.

echo "<pre>";
// will echo success , for debugging we can uncomment echo 
print_r($output);

// also want to add redirect to this script to send back to profile 
after upload

echo "The file was uploaded";

//echo print_r($output); //  Report of command excution process.

            echo "</pre>";

if($ext !== 'mp3'){ // If the uploaded file mp3 which is not remove 
from uploaded directory because we need to convert in to .mp3
unlink( $uploadFile );
}

 //0644 vs 0777
chmod( $finalFile, 0777 ); // Set uploaded file the permission.


 }
 else
{
echo "Uploading failed"; //If uploding failed.
}

?>
```

Comment: In this `$aditionalnewFileName = $bandname.="_".` code, you are appending the content to the variable `$bandname` as well as setting `$aditionalnewFileName` to the result.  You need to change the `.=` to just a `.`.

Comment: Just tried that but still not working the var_dump($bandname); still outputs string(88) "_police.ogg_police.ogg_police.ogg_police.ogg_police.mp3_police.mp3_police.mp3_police.wav"

Comment: Have you cleared out the SESSION as this may be done elsewhere.

Comment: ill try that and see if that works

Comment: I cleared the session now it's just showing NULL NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after a while, I decided to go about it a different way. I used mysqli,i quarried the user name and bandname, then used the while loop used var_dump noticed bandname after staring at my code i saw i was editing the wrong line so i change   $aditionofileName  = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-_\'.]/', '',$bandname . 
$_FILES['song_name']['name']); and change the line i thought was the problem to $aditionalnewFileName = "_".$aditionofileName; revmoed variable and removed the .
new code below.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset      ($_SESSION ['band_id'  ]))
{
$band_id  = $_SESSION ['band_id'  ];
$bandname = $_SESSION ['bandname' ];
$username = $_SESSION ['username' ];
}

if (isset      ($_GET ['band_id']))
{                               // Yes
$showband = $_GET ['band_id'];
}
else
{                               // No
  echo "ID not set";       // Just show the member 
}

include 'connect.php';

$sql     = "SELECT * from members WHERE band_id=$showband";

$result  = mysqli_query ($dbhandle, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
$username = $row ["username"    ];
$bandname = $row ["bandname"    ];
}

var_dump($bandname);

ini_set( "max_execution_time", "3600" ); // sets the maximum execution time of 
this script to 1 hour.

$uploads_dir     = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mp3';

$aditiontmp_name = $_FILES['song_name']['tmp_name']; // get client side file 
tmp_name 
// '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_\'.]/', ''   //$_FILES['song_name']['name']);
$aditionofileName  = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_\'.]/', '',$bandname . 
$_FILES['song_name']['name']); // get client side file name remove the special 
character with preg_replace function.

// remove time() to edit name of mp3
$aditionalnewFileName = "_".$aditionofileName; //filename changed with current 
time
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injection; use a prepared statement. That's how databases get deleted.